# printing in one line in python 3.4

Tags: python

I want program to print in one line but keep these two lines in code. How to do that ? I tryed to use comma but it's same

```
print(end1 + end2 + end3 + end4 + end5 + end6)

print(end7 + end8 + end9 + end10 + end11 + end12)
```

Comment: What's with the numbered variables? If this was a list you could `print(*end, sep='')` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3, you now can specify and set the `end` param value to empty string in the first print statement.

```
print(end1 + end2 + end3 + end4 + end5 + end6, end="")
print(end7 + end8 + end9 + end10 + end11 + end12)
```

Comment: thanks one more thing how to make space betweene these two ? cuz now they are joined.

Comment: `print(end1 + end2 + end3 + end4 + end5 + end6, end=" ")`

Comment: Oh I must be stupid. Last time I tryed and probably forgot to save so there was no difference. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space) is essentially your question, though slightly more involved.

The end of the answer is that appending a comma outside the printed string will allow you to put multiple `print` statements on one line.

Ex):

```
for i in range(0,5):
    print i
```

Will give you

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

But

```
for i in range(0,5):
    print i,
```

Will give you
    `0 1 2 3 4`

In case that doesn't work for some reason, you can always use the `\b` backspace character to back out the linebreak the print whatever you want

Ex:

```
print("Hello")
print("\b World")
```

Comment: Tested using Pythoni on my iPhone iOS 8.3